# Discord API call to get guild channels

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

I am trying to get all channels from a discord guild with an API call. I am making this request in python with `requests` but unfortunately I only get '{'message': '401: Unauthorized', 'code': 0}'.

My request and response:

```
headers = {
   'Authorization': f'Bot {bot_access_token}'
}

channels_url = f'https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/{server_id}/channels'
response = requests.get(channels_url, headers)

print(response.json()) # {'message': '401: Unauthorized', 'code': 0}
```

I have tried this request with Postman and there it works :(

What am I missing?

I think maybe I am missing the User-Agent but if that is the case I don't know what I should type in.

**[UPDATE 1]**

To be more precise, I am calling `requests` in a view (django framework). I let my bot join my server with administration rights and this scopes: identify, guilds and bot.

I tried this 'User-Agent's:

- 'User-Agent': 'MyBotName'
- 'User-Agent': 'MyBotName/1.0'

**[UPDATE 2]**

So I already read the Discord Documentation about [API call which includes User Agent for http](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#http-api) (before I wrote this Question post).

> User-Agent: DiscordBot ($url, $versionNumber)

In this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordbots/comments/wlx0ep/user_agents_for_a_bot/) it seems the url should be the generated bot join url and for version number - just choose one.

I tried it but with no different result.

Comment: Have you already integrate your bot to that channel like this one?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPTFAfVut84

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan I don't have access to that Video but I saw the thumbnail for 1 sec. I have invited the bot to my server with the scopes: identify, guild, and bot. Is that the content of the video?

Comment: Yes, just make sure your bot is already member channel. But from your update, you did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple but a stupid Problem.

I added my header to the requests like this:

`response = requests.get(channels_url, headers)`

Instead of this:

`response = requests.get(channels_url, headers=headers)`

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests

headers = {
   'Authorization': f'Bot {bot_access_token}',
   'User-Agent': 'YourBotNameHere'
}

channels_url = f'https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/{server_id}/channels'
response = requests.get(channels_url, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

If setting the user agent doesn't resolve the issue, make sure you have the correct bot_access_token and server_id values. You could also verify that the bot has been properly added to the guild and has the necessary permissions to access the channels.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried add the User-Agent with the name of my bot but the result is not different. As I said I tried this request on Postman and it worked - I used the access token from the bot and the same server id.

Comment: I was using the access token I got after Oauth2. Bot token works perfect! Thank you!